# Like Button arent working properly

Tags: button, iframe, share, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

The like button on the left and the like button after the post – on my web site aren't working properly (zabavax.com) when you click the like button the countdown of the likes works fine but the post(link) does not share ti on facebook users on their timeline i.e the post they have liked on the web site does not appear on the timeline layout, nor does it appear on the news feed of the user's friends. I noticed that the likes of the facebook users who have timeline(layout) are shown only at the activity log. As for the classic facebook layout users, their likes (of the posts on my web site)appear on their wall but the like is not shared (shown) on the user's friend's wall via news feed feature. I have also included comment plugin for facebook and it works fine (shares on facebook as it should).

Answer (score 0):

i even can not click on like buttons

you are using js sdk i recommend you to use iframe Like Button

Comment: i dont use js sdk i use iframe like button

Answer (score 0):

This may be a temporary situation. For last 2 days I see this for many sites. 
Did you try other sites like-share buttons and see if they appeared on your timeline.